# return nothing when 1 table is empty between 2 table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
  A.AccID,
  ISNULL(A.Camt, 0) AS Camt,
  ISNULL(B.Damt, 0) AS Damt
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(J.Amount) AS Camt,
    J.AccID
  FROM dbo.Journal AS J
  INNER JOIN dbo.Voucher AS V ON J.Vid = V.Vid
  WHERE
    J.DRCR = 'D' AND
    AccID = 1200181
  GROUP BY J.AccID
  ) AS A
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(J.Amount) AS Damt,
    J.AccID
  FROM dbo.Journal AS J
  INNER JOIN dbo.Voucher AS V ON J.Vid = V.Vid
  WHERE
    J.DRCR = 'C' AND
    AccID = 1200181
  GROUP BY J.AccID
  ) AS B ON A.AccID = B.AccID
```

this return nothing when sub-query A or sub-query B is Empty.

i want to return if any table have data. is it possible?

Comment: This can't be true... you probably have both empty.

Comment: I agree with last comment, since you are using FULL OUTER JOIN you can't get no result if either of the sub-queries has any record.  FULL OUTER JOIN will you empty result only when both the sub-queries are empty.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I believe your answer is within a wrong assumption of your data. Nevertheless, wouldn't the following query give you the result you're looking for (given the data is correct)?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN J.DRCR = 'D' THEN J.Amount END) AS Damt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN J.DRCR = 'C' THEN J.Amount END) AS Camt,
  J.AccID
FROM dbo.Journal AS J
--INNER JOIN dbo.Voucher AS V ON J.Vid = V.Vid
WHERE j.AccID = 1200181
GROUP BY J.AccID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN J.DRCR IN ('D','C') THEN J.Amount END) > 0
```

Notice the commented table, I didn't see any use for it in your existing query. The only function might be to filter rows from `Journal` which do not match `Voucher`.

Comment: really awesome answer.thank you.but i have solved my problem by changing in  ON isnull(A.AccID,B.AccID ) = isnull(B.AccID,A.AccID) if one table does not return any id then he join with self id.